When I arrange two 3d-plots using Grid, position of axes-y changes
I want to arrange two 3d-plots, for example
Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> "RustTones"]

which gives

where the position of y-axis is marked by the red arrow.
However, when I arrage such two 3d-plots,
Grid[{{%, %}}]


However, y-axis moves to the top. Why so? How to keep y-axis at the orignal position?
Thank you!

plot =
  Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
   ColorFunction -> "RustTones"];

Using GraphicsRow
GraphicsRow[{plot, plot}, Dividers -> All, FrameStyle -> LightGray]


Using GraphicsGrid
GraphicsGrid[{{plot, plot}}, Dividers -> All, FrameStyle -> LightGray]


output like above

If you have to use Grid the problem disappears by specifying the AxesEdge - option
plot =
  Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
   AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
   ColorFunction -> "RustTones"];

Grid[{{plot, plot}}]


